# How to do a 3D line fit with robust regression (based on the absolute deviation rather than least square)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am conversant with fitting a 3D line based on the least square plane but I would be glad to know how to do this using robust regression ( that is by minimizing the  sum of absolute differences instead of the sum of the squares.

If I try to apply the same technique throigh which the least square plane is derived. ( by finding the partial derivatives with respect to of the distance from a plane equation R=(Ax+BY+Cz+D)^2 Then my set of derivatives result in equations that are simply not useful if the square is removed from the above equation.